# Excel DATE IF Condition

Tags: excel, date, if-statement

Excel formula required as per the following conditions:

Conditions:

```
After   Date after 31/07/2017   
Before  Date after 12/10/2016 & Before 01/08/2017   
Old Date after 12/10/2015 & Before 12/10/2016   
Very Old    Date Before 12/10/2015
```

Output as follows

```
Date            Status
12-03-2014      Very Old
10-03-2015      Very Old
11-02-2016      Old
05-05-2016      Old
22-12-2016      Before
25-01-2017      Before
28-02-2017      Before
20-03-2017      Before
19-06-2017      Before
20-07-2017      Before
21-07-2017      Before
10-08-2017      After
25-08-2017      After
29-08-2017      After
01-09-2017      After
08-09-2017      After
```

Please help
CSGanesh

Answer (score 2):

Create a table with the start dates and the expected outcome:

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP()

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A:B,2,TRUE)
```

[image]

---

If you do not want to use a table but want hard-coded formula then:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(D2,{0,42289,42655,42947}),"Very Old","Old","Before","After")
```

`{0,42289,42655,42947}` are the dates in general format and can be replaced with the actual dates in quotes; `{"1/0/1900","12/10/2015",...}`

[image]

Comment: Your conditions have gaps e.g. Very Old    Date Before 12/10/2015 and Old Date after 12/10/2015 & Before 12/10/2016  excludes 12/10/2015 etc. Is this intended?

Comment: @QHarr I have no gaps, did you intend to ask the OP?

Comment: absolutely meant the OP. Apologies i did not make that clear and posted in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. But it shows some field error.  I give below correct conditions :  (After-   Date  31/07/2017 ),   
(Before- Date Between 12/10/2016 and  01/08/2017 ),  
(Old- Date Between 12/10/2015  and  12/10/2016 )  
(Very Old -  Date Before 12/10/2015)

Comment: My dates are US format `mm/dd/yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy` like yours but they are the same. @user2579235

Comment: OK Sir, but it shows some field error :  i.e .date 08-02-2017 result shows #N/A, Date 01-09-2016 result shows #N/A) . My file is more than 4000 rows. Some records shows above error. Please help

Comment: Then your dates are not true dates but text strings that look like dates, you will need to parse them to true dates.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a nested if statment here is a link:

https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example

here are the first two conditions, excel can interpret time intervals so lock a cell with the conditions and then drag the formula. Remember to verify that the cell is indeed a date.

IF(date<12/10/15,"Very old",IF(AND(D6>12/10/15,date<12/10/16),"old",0))

Comment: Thank you for your immediate help.  But it shows error like #NAME?
Please help

Comment: Did you test this? As written Excel will interpret 12/10/15 as the calculation 12 divided by 10 divided by 15, giving you a very small number, not a date, you either need to use DATE function like DATE(2015,12,10) or in quotes with a co-ercer like "12/10/15"+0

Comment: you have to change 'date' and the dates for values in cells I tested it and it works